# Acces denied when Scaffolding on MySql database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core

i want to use entity framework core on my .Net Core project to connect to mysql db. i got an access denied error when i try to scaffold.

```
Authentication to host 'MyHost.com' for user 'root' using method 'caching_sha2_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'root'@'MYIP' (using password: YES)
```

i'm using this comand

```
Scaffold-DbContext "server=MyHost.com;port=9999;user=root;password=Myunbreakablepsw;database=MyDb" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir dbContext -f
```

Thx

EDIT :

I had a $ in the password. This caracter need to be escaped with ` so it's correctly identified as a normal caracter in the string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your password probably has a problematic character in it.  For me it was '$'.  That's fine in normal use but the Scaffold-DbContext command chokes on it.  Change your password.

Comment: I already found the problem but i forgot to update my post. My issue was with the $ too. i just had to escape this characters with a ` and it works ! Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

A common error also that is Scaffolding is Case Sensitive, check if MyDb is the realname of the database with the respectivase case, like "myDB"